# check if google maps app is installed in react-native iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I tried with the npm module `react-native-check-app-install` but I couldn't achieved always the result is false.

Also tried with `react-native-installed-apps` to get the list of apps installed in the phone but this return always empty list.

Comment: use `react-native-installed-packages`

Comment: I think it only works for android :thinking:

Comment: yes its only for android

Comment: Question says IOS :(

Comment: sorry bro  btw i found this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-check-app-install

use `isAppInstalledIOS(url)` this might work

Comment: Do you know the correct url for google maps please

Comment: https://github.com/redpandatronicsuk/react-native-check-app-install/blob/master/app-list.js

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you make sure to declare the URL schemes?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_6_declare_the_url_schemes_used_by_the_api

Once you've done that, you don't need an additional package to check if you can open Google Maps. You can just use the Linking module.

```
Linking.canOpenURL('comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866')
.then((canOpen) => {
    if (canOpen) { console.log('open google maps'); } else { console.log('open apple maps'); }
});
```

Comment: Updated link for URL schemes mentioned in the answer: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_6_declare_the_url_schemes_used_by_the_api

Comment: When compiling with iOS SDK 9.0 and later, you must update your application's property list file with the following to include Waze:
`<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>comgooglemaps</string>
  <string>waze</string>
</array>`

Comment: Is it possible to just if opening google maps is installed? Without passing coordinates? For instance, does something like this ```Linking.canOpenURL('comgooglemaps://)```work? @AbhishekGhosh

Comment: @Jnl should definitely be possible :)