# Get AppList in iPhone using React Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, react-native

I have a requirement where I need to check whether either of two applications exist in iPhone device. Both the apps are live on Appstore. I am coding in react native and Ia m new to it. I have LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in my info.Plist and added URL types, where URL identifier is my Bundle Identifier and URLScheme is same as LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. Example- CRM_EDGE.app, UpperMOSt.app. I have tried renaming the URL Scheme. None works.

Sites I have gone through:
https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/5msem6/how_to_get_list_of_installed_applications/
[How can i check app installed in react native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44005242/how-can-i-check-app-installed-in-react-native-code)
[check if google maps app is installed in react-native iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652375/check-if-google-maps-app-is-installed-in-react-native-ios)

I tried two libraries for executing this.

1. react-native-check-app-install

Problem -- Applist.js returns hard coded values and after uninstalling it still returns isInstalled 'true'

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-check-app-install

2. react-native-installed-apps

Problem -- The developer who developed this, didnt checked on device, so works in simulator not on device. And the issue is still open.
[image]

Please suggest what to do to get proper Applist so that I can check if the required apps exist on device.

Comment: Version 0.0.5 means it is just an alpha, not even meant to be used in production. Find other library or look inside the library how it is done and what is failing

Comment: @MarekH thank you for your response. Can you please suggest a working library for this? I tried going through the library files, but as I am a newbie, I am not able to execute this. Please help!

Comment: So, I got the solution to this. Rather than using any third party, I used Linking which is react-native inbuilt. And following the deeplinking concepts in iOS, I was able to achieve my task. Thanks All:)